# Automapper - Creating Maps in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, automapper

Was just getting started with AutoMapper and wanted to get clarity on something.

Let's say I want to seamlessly map between a User and a UserDto.

The examples all seem to suggest that I must first go to a startup area (for example WebApiConfig.cs or startup.cs or global.axax etc) and do something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserDto>();
```

Presumably if I had 50 or 100 entities/DTOs that I wanted to map, I would need to literally add 50 or 100 lines of code with mappings between one class to another? Surely there's a smarter way, right?

If I don't ever need to do any specific mapping / overriding, do I really need to do this? I must have misunderstood the fundamentals of the framework because that just seems wrong to me.

Thanks!

Comment: `Surely there's a smarter way, right?`. Not really. Unless you want to do it via reflection. But then you have the problem if *in the future* you want a *specific rule for a specific mapping*.

Comment: wow ok thanks. I felt like the fact that i'm manually writing out the mapping in my controller (when I want to map between two things) is sufficient for mapper to understand the two types, but I guess not. Ok thanks

Comment: Did you understand (from reading the docs) that you can create all the mappings you need in one class let's say EntityToViewModel and just register that class in your global.asax? Creating them in the controller will propably generate some duplicate code, and I guess this is what you are concerned?

Comment: One thing (a HUGE thing) you'll miss with dynamic mapping is configuration validation. If you typo something, or rename, you won't get any runtime failures. You'll just have an unmapped property with no value. Don't take shortcuts here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as **everything** matches up on the source and the target, you could use `DynamicMap`:

```
var target = Mapper.DynamicMap<TSource, TTarget>(source);
```

However it would be more efficient to create a mapping as required:

```
if (Mapper.FindTypeMapFor<TSource, TTarget>() == null)
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<TSource, TTarget>();
}

var target =  Mapper.Map<TSource, TTarget>(source);
```